# What is verbosity in bitcoin-cli command arguments?

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I have come across a couple of `bitcoin-cli` commands where an additional verbosity parameter is needed to fetch additional information about the command, for example `getblock “blockhash” ( verbosity )` will require verbosity values of 0, 1 or 2.
What is verbosity and what does it do and how is it used?
Is it something you set in the config?

Comment: You mean like https://bitcoin-rpc.github.io/en/doc/0.17.99/rpc/blockchain/getblock/? Seems like just trying it would probably also answer the question.

Comment: I am confused as to how it is used in real life. All i see is a straight `getblock` call with the blockhash without any reference made to the verbosity

Answer (score 1):

Verbosity refers to the amount of information and detail provided. As the documentation for `getblock` says:

> If verbosity is 0, returns a string that is serialized, hex-encoded data for block 
>   'hash'.
>   If verbosity is 1, returns an Object with information about block .
>   If verbosity is 2, returns an Object with information about block  and information about each transaction.

Comment: How is it used? I see only a request with just one parameter from the example provided in the documentation

Comment: You just add a second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

On newer bitcoin core nodes versions, you have a verbosity level of 3, which will fetch you the UTXO for the inputs, hence resolving their amount and input address that were not provided before with verbosity 2 or less.
Beware though, I have seen in the past bitcoin nodes would not generate addresses for P2PK addresses, so you might also need a script like the following to generate addresses for those edge cases yourself:

```js
// will take a public key from a p2pk transaction and convert it to an address
function p2pkToAddress(pubkey) {
    // working example: http://gobittest.appspot.com/Address
    // parse hexa
    let pk = Buffer.from(pubkey, "hex");
    // hash the pubkey with SHA256
    let firstHashSha256 = crypto.createHash("sha256");
    firstHashSha256.update(pk);
    // hash the sha256 with ripemd-160
    let secondHashRipeMD = crypto.createHash("ripemd160");
    secondHashRipeMD.update(firstHashSha256.digest());
    // add network bytes 00 to the second hash
    let strHash2 = secondHashRipeMD.digest("hex");
    let secondHashWithPrefix = Buffer.from("00" + strHash2, "hex");
    // perform another sha256
    let thirdHashSha256 = crypto.createHash("sha256");
    thirdHashSha256.update(secondHashWithPrefix);
    // do it again
    let fourthHashSha256 = crypto.createHash("sha256");
    fourthHashSha256.update(thirdHashSha256.digest());
    // isolate the first four bytes of the 4th hash
    let fourthHashPrefix = fourthHashSha256.digest().slice(0, 4);
    let fourthHashPrefixStr = fourthHashPrefix.toString("hex");
    // concatenates first 4 bytes of fourth hash with the secondHash with network prefix
    let combinedHashes = Buffer.from(secondHashWithPrefix.toString("hex") + fourthHashPrefixStr, "hex");
    // base58 encode the string
    let result = bs58.encode(combinedHashes);
    return result;
}
```